# Using PdfDocument class for old android version

Tags: android, pdf, pdf-generation

Is there any support class for `PdfDocument` so it could be used by older android version (< kitkat)?

What i need is something like `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager` for `PdfDocument`.

Thanks your time.

Answer (score 0):

No, this feature has not been implemented in any of the support libraries.

I would guess they are not able to backport it due to dependencies on the underlying graphics subsystem.